# How to run .swf file in iPhone using Adobe Flash CS5?

Tags: iphone, flash, ios5, flash-cs5

I have 5 .swf files only, created by Flash Professional CS5.. no .xml and no .fla file.. I got it from my team member.. now I want to run that .swf file in iPhone.. How can i run it in device..? Is am i need to convert that .swf file using decompilers or Is there any other solution.

Comment: _Jailbreak -> Cydia -> Flash player._ there is no official way to play any flash content on your device. the Apple does not support this format. have you heard the news 5 years ago?

Comment: No, I didn't heard about that.But In the following link http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=116 we can see that an app developed in flash running in an iPhone.. I am working on flash just from 4 days.. please help me

Comment: honestly...? it looks like a limited `IDE` with an under-supported `API`.  good luck for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just simple animation then you may have some luck using Google's Swiffy tool which can convert a swf file to html/svg which will run on an iPhone.

https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Answer (score 0):

There is no flash support in iOS.

Comment: In the following link http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=116 we can see that an app developed in flash running in an iPhone.. I am working on flash just from 4 days.. please help me

Comment: To do this, you'd need the fla file to compile it as an iOS app.

Comment: How can i get it from .swf file..?

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS doesn't support Flash. Alternative You can convert .swf Files to HTML(5) on the server side and play.